# Firebase Firestore and Storage Get URL and use within query loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

In the below code, I am trying to get the image URLs based on the Firestore doc.id. I'm able to get them, but because this is basically a promise within a promise, I'm not getting expected result. The URL is empty in the htmlItems string.

What is the proper way to get the URL of the imaage where the filename matches the doc.id?

```
  var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  var htmlItems = "";
  const storage = firebase.storage();
  var imageURL = "";
  
    db.collection("items").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            
            storage.ref(doc.id+'.jpg').getDownloadURL()
              .then((url) => {
                // Do something with the URL ...
                imageURL = url;
              })

             
            htmlItems += '<div class="col mb-5"><div class="card h-100"><img class="card-img-top" src="'+imageURL+'" alt="..." /><div class="card-body p-4"><div class="text-center"><h5 class="fw-bolder">'+doc.data().title+'</h5>'+doc.data().price+'</div></div><div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">'+whichSport(doc.data().sport)+'<div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-darkmt-auto" href="#">View options</a></div></div></div></div>';
            
            console.log(doc.id, " ====> ", doc.data());

            
        });
              $('#items').html(htmlItems);
    });
```

Comment: It seems you misunderstand how promises work in JavaScript.  They are asynchronous, and calls to `then` on a promise return immediately before the callback function is invoked.  You are trying to use the values of the query results before they are available.  You'll likely have to reconsider entirely how your code is suppose to work in order to account for this behavior.